# How to provide feedback on Windows beta versions?

Tags: windows, windows-8-preview, windows-8.1-preview

How can I report bugs and request new features for newly released Windows versions, or beta versions?

Comment: Technically Windows 8.1 Preview isn't a beta.  Looking through Microsoft's eyes  it's actually more of a customer/developer preview at this point.  Which based on the Windows 8 preview builds they took very little feedback.  They have a specific goal in mind with Windows 8.1 which is transparent based on the changes that were made.

Answer (score 1):

When Microsoft wants bug reports and suggestions for any of their products they will list them on their bug/suggestion tracker: [connect.microsoft.com](https://connect.microsoft.com/).

Currently the only Windows 8.1 edition listed is "Windows Embedded 8.1 Industry Pro Release Preview", so that means they are not currently accepting bug reports or suggestions for other versions/editions.